# numpy.sin(pi) returns negative value

Tags: python, numpy, approximation, trigonometry

The following code:

```
a = numpy.sin(2. * numpy.pi)
print(a < 0)
```

return "True". But in reality a = 0. How could I fix that? In addition, I have a matrix with a lot of value like "a" and I want to make sure that my matrix contains non-negative value.

Comment: Note that this is not NumPy specific, the builtin `math.sin` and `math.pi` also give a result < 0.

Comment: Interestingly, the result of `numpy.arccos(numpy.float128(-1))` is a more accurate approximation of π than `numpy.pi`. You can find the decimal expansion here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Approximate_value

Answer (score 4):

This because of floating point arithmetic, and accuracy reasons. The result is the best approximation of `sin` one can get to be representable as a floating point number. Usually you solve near-zero problems like this:

```
a = numpy.sin(2. * numpy.pi)
print(abs(a) < 1e-10)
```

You may also want to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 2):

In reality a <> 0 because in reality `numpy.pi` is not Pi (what is Pi in reality anyway?) - it is just its approximation and `numpy.sin` is not sine - it is its approximation as well. So you have to take some error into account, for example

```
print( -0.0000001 < a < 0.0000001 )
```

or use some other tricks (representing Pi differently - not as a float number ).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, obviously english is not my native language. :)

Comment: `sin` is more Latin via Arabic via Sanskrit than English *per se*, but I'll let it slide this once!

Comment: certainly not `-0.0000001 < a and a < 0.0000001`.  chain operators `-0.0000001 < a < 0.0000001` or use `abs(a) < 1e-7` or use `numpy.allclose`

Comment: @wim And what if I don't?

Comment: don't like constructive criticism?  then continue to write ugly code.

Comment: @wim I don't like nibbling. It does not matter at all in the context of OP's question. And "ugliness" is a matter of opinion. But I will fix it so to please the audience. :)

Comment: It is totally in context.  I'm offering some improvements, not attacking you, so grow up and don't take it in such an immature fashion.

Comment: @wim Right, because nibbling is very mature. :) But as you can see I'm a reasonable man - I won't argue with you.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.sin(2. * numpy.pi)
>>> numpy.allclose(a, 0)
True
>>> numpy.clip(numpy.array([-0.1, 1.0, 2.0]), 0, np.inf)
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.])
```

Answer (score 0):

When I calculate

```
numpy.sin(2 * numpy.pi)
```

I get

```
-2.4492935982947064e-16 # i.e. -0.0000000000000002
```

This is a classic `float`ing point accuracy error. You are better taking a tolerance approach to testing the value:

```
if abs(a) < 0.0001:
```

Comment: I disagree with statement that the main reason is floating point inaccuracy (although it does affect it). Both sine and Pi are not mathematical sine and Pi. They are approximations. For example in my Python I see `numpy.pi == 3.141592653589793`. Assuming that `numpy.sin` is a simple implementation of its Taylor series (well, it does really matter how implemented it is - obviously it is an approximation), then even if do calculations in "real" arithmetic you will still get wrong result.

Comment: @freakish This approximation of pi is exact up to 16 significant positions, which is just the accuracy of a double-precision float aka double and I would presume that a good implementation of `sin` will have an error not large than one epsilon (that is the relative float precision). This is possible to implement with an appropriate Taylor series.

Comment: @freakish The approximate nature of both `sin` and `pi` is due to the use of floating point arithmetic, though. A symbolic math system could represent `pi` as just a symbol and use pattern matching to get an exact `sin(pi)`.

Comment: @larsmans Not quite. Actually approximations of both sine and pi existed long time before floating point arithmetic was invented. People did calculate them with "real" arithmetic as well (and with the same "error problem"). These are two quite independent things.