# Why is numpy's sine function so inaccurate at some points?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I just checked `numpy`'s `sine` function. Apparently, it produce highly inaccurate results around pi.

```
In [26]: import numpy as np

In [27]: np.sin(np.pi)
Out[27]: 1.2246467991473532e-16
```

The expected result is 0.  Why is `numpy` so inaccurate there?

To some extend, I feel uncertain whether it is acceptable to regard the calculated result as inaccurate: Its absolute error comes within one machine epsilon (for binary64), whereas the relative error is `+inf` -- reason why I feel somewhat confused. Any idea?

[Edit] I fully understand that floating-point calculation can be inaccurate. But most of the floating-point libraries can manage to deliver results within a small range of error. Here, the relative error is +inf, which seems unacceptable. Just imagine that we want to calculate

```
1/(1e-16 + sin(pi))
```

The results would be disastrously wrong if we use numpy's implementation.

Comment: You did notice the `e-16` there, right?

Comment: "So inaccurate" is relative I guess...the difference between 0 and 0.00000000000000012246468 is relatively small considering the computers ability to accurately represent the infinite sequence pi

Comment: @FredLarson Yes. I did notice the e-16 part.  As mentioned above,  its absolute error comes within one machine epsilon (for binary64), whereas the relative error is +inf

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903384/numpy-sinpi-returns-negative-value) is a very similar SO thread - floats can only be so accurate and the [allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) method is useful in arrays to check if values are 'close enough'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: Also, it's inaccurate to say that relative error is "+Inf" - "[relative error is undefined when the true value is zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error#Uses_of_relative_error)".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem here is that `np.pi` is not exactly π, it's a finite binary floating point number that is close to the true irrational real number π but still off by ~1e-16. `np.sin(np.pi)` is actually returning a value closer to the true infinite-precision result for `sin(np.pi)` (i.e. the ideal mathematical `sin()` function being given the approximated `np.pi` value) than 0 would be.

Comment: a = np.sin(np.pi) ...    np.allclose(a, np.PZERO)  # True ... np.allclose(a, np.NZERO)  # True  can be used to produce a 'zero' if you don't like current representation

Answer (score 0):

my_wave = np.sin(np.arange(0, length, length / resolution))

The set of numbers supplied by np.arrange are correct increment x+=0.06283185

[using sin(arrange) with Excel as expected ]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS6GC.png

[Using np.sin(arrange) with numpy very wrong]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6qnZ.png

Using math.sin with the same set of numbers is also good.
Using mp.sin with the same set of numbers is also good.

The problem is calling mp.sin with a pointer to the array
my_wave = np.sin(np.arange(0, length, length / resolution))
isn't good

However mp.arrange is also good

Answer (score -1):

The value is dependent upon the algorithm used to compute it.  A typical implementation will use some quickly-converging infinite series, carried out until it converges within one machine epsilon.  Many modern chips (starting with the Intel 960, I think) had such functions in the instruction set.

To get 0 returned for this, we would need either a notably more accurate algorithm, one that ran extra-precision arithmetic to guarantee the closest-match result, or something that recognizes special cases: detect a multiple of PI and return the exact value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just using a look-up table, not an iterative algorithm.  Also `np.pi` is just a float so it's only approximately equal to pi.

Comment: I tried looking up what NumPy does; can't find it.  Do you have a reference, perhaps?  I'd like to know whether it doesn't bother with the native chip functions; the software I work with "trusts" the chip, so a good reference could teach me a few things and utterly torpedo this answer.

Comment: It might use the [C library implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2285277/10077).

Comment: “detect a multiple of PI and return the exact value” is easy. The only multiple of π representable as a floating-point number is 0. There is no reason to invoke algorithm inaccuracy here: the result shown in the question seems about right for sine applied to the nearest binary64 approximation of  π.

Comment: To get 0 returned for this, we'd need a much *less* accurate algorithm. In this case, `np.sin` is returning the best possible answer that it could possibly give for the given input of `np.pi` (which is exactly equal to `3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875`). It's returning the closest representable float to the true mathematical answer, with an absolute error of around `3e-33`, or about `0.12` ulps. In contrast, an answer of `0` would have an absolute error of around `1e-16`, and would be billions of ulps out.

Comment: @PascalCuoq This is a user-surprise issue: the user put in the package-defined representation of π, and has reasonable expectation of getting an answer of 0.  As a QA engineer, I'd file a bug; as an implementation engineer, I'd close it as "will not fix".  :-)